# How do I detect the last iteration in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I tried doing this first:

```
$e = 0;

$objectsid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xw_char_items WHERE CharId = '$charid' AND ItemCat = 'object' ORDER BY SortOrder ASC");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($objectsid)) {

  $e++;
  if($e==9) break;

  $objectsinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xw_objects WHERE ItemId = '{$obj["ItemId"]}'");
  $object = mysql_fetch_array($objectsinfo);

  echo "&charid$e={$char["Id"]}";
  if($objectsid == end($obj)) {
  echo "&intActiveObject=1";
  echo "&intObjectsNum=$e";
  }
}
```

Here it never detects the last one. I also tried this:

```
$e = 0;
$len = count($objectsid));

while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($objectsid)) {

  $e++;
  if($e==9) break;

  $objectsinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xw_objects WHERE ItemId = '{$obj["ItemId"]}'");
  $object = mysql_fetch_array($objectsinfo);
  mysql_free_result($objectsinfo);

  echo "&charid$e={$char["Id"]}";
  if ($e == $len - 1) {
  echo "&intActiveObject=1";
  echo "&intObjectsNum=$e";
  }
}
```

Here it detects every iteration as the last one.

Does anyone how to make it detect the last iteration?

Comment: Its a mess. Rewrite it, but this time using PDO rather than the`mysql_` API

Answer (score -1):

The `$objectsid` variable is storing the `mysql_result` object not the array of your fetched rows. So even if you apply `count($objectsid)`, you will not get the length of your fetched array.

So the right method is to use `mysql_num_rows()`.

So Simply do this `$len=mysql_num_rows($objectsid);` and the rest will workout as you are expecting. :)

Comment: Please, read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I know, but the asker is coding with mysql_* so I had to give him solution in that domain :/.

I know he/she shouldn't use it, but still he/she should know about those functions. He/she will eventually find out PDO or mysqli_